# Using `Add-Type` within a Function. Memory Leak?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

If the `Add-Type` function is called to add a snippet of C# code within a function, will the "type" be garbage-collected once the function has finished executing? Or will the type still exist in memory because it was part of a (virtual) assembly that was loaded into the AppDomain? (Thus being a "memory leak")

In the below `Lock-WorkStation` definition, `Add-Type` is used to add a code written in C#:

```bsh
function Lock-WorkStation {
    $signature = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool LockWorkStation();
'@

    $name = "Win32LockWorkStation"
    $LockWorkStation = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name $name -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru
    $LockWorkStation::LockWorkStation() | Out-Null
}
```

My question is, if this function is called multiple types, then it is constantly parsing and adding the C# code as a (virtual) assembly. (Or is it garbage-collected?)

Is it better to write it as:

```bsh
Function Lock-WorkStation {
    if (!$Global:LockWorkStation) {
        $signature = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool LockWorkStation();
'@
        $name = "Win32LockWorkStation"
        $global:LockWorkStation = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name $name -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru
    }

    $global:LockWorkStation::LockWorkStation() | Out-Null
}
```

So that the C# code is only instantiated as an assembly once?

Comment: `Add-Type` have optimization to reuse result of previous compilation, if called with exactly same string: `[Object]::ReferenceEquals((Add-Type 'class C { }' -PassThru), (Add-Type 'class C { }' -PassThru))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Mathias for your answer.  My question, however, was about whether calling `Add-Type` instantiates the type each time it is called.  I looked at the documentation, which says:

> The type name and namespace must be **unique** within a session. You cannot unload a type or change it. If you need to change the code for a type, you must change the name or start a new Windows PowerShell session. Otherwise, the command fails. ([Add-Type Documentation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type)

`Add-Type` will instantiate the type the first time it is called. On subsequent calls with the same arguments, because the type already exists, it will do nothing.  Therefore, the only reason to include an `if` condition over the `Add-Type` statement, is for efficiency reasons, because a call to `Add-Type` has the overhead of checking if the type already exists.

Your `if` condition:

```
-not ($LockWorkStation = "$namespace.$name" -as [type])
```

IMHO, is not efficient because it uses string interpolation to compute the type name, then it checks if the type exists, then it assigns the type to a variable, each time it runs.

Instead, you can set the type variable once (the scope being `Script:`).  The `if` statement can check if it is null, and if so, instantiate it:

```
function Lock-WorkStation {
    if ($Script:Win32LockWorkStation -eq $null) {
        $namespace = 'Win32Functions'
        $name = 'Win32LockWorkStation'

        $signature = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool LockWorkStation();
'@
        $Script:Win32LockWorkStation = Add-Type -Namespace $namespace -Name $name -MemberDefinition $signature -PassThru
    }

    $Script:Win32LockWorkStation::LockWorkStation() | Out-Null
}
```

If you wish, you can check my [performance comparison](http://tahirhassan.blogspot.co.uk/2017/04/powershell-performance-of-different.html) of different ways of using `Add-Type` within a function.

Answer (score 1):

Test if the resulting type already exists:

```
function Lock-WorkStation {
    $name = 'Win32LockWorkStation'
    $namespace = 'Win32Functions'
    $signature = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool LockWorkStation();
'@
    if(-not ($LockWorkStation = "$namespace.$name" -as [type])){
        $LockWorkStation = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name $name -Namespace $namespace -PassThru
    }
    $LockWorkStation::LockWorkStation() | Out-Null
}
```